# Ubuntu as hsp/hfp sink

Tags: bluetooth, pulseaudio

I would like to use my laptop as a HSP/HPF Bluetooth **SINK**. Is there an easy way to do so? I've got a2dp profile working. However, my Icom IC-705 could connect just to HSP/HPF headset.

The IC-705 could connect to cheap Bluetooth headphones and use them as microphone and headphones. Would it be possible with ubuntu 20.04 pc?